# html css issue with text and button

Tags: html, css, forms

```
        <div class="login-form-container">
            <div class="w-auto d-flex justify-content-center alert" role="alert"> 
                <h4>Password is activated</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="w-100 justify-content-center d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button type="button" @onclick="@ToHomePage" class="login-button" role="button">Home</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem I am having with the code is, it shows the "Password is activated" message and button in the same line but I want the message in one line and the button in another line. Any idea how to resolve this?

[The page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaxaN.jpg)

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: Consider removing ```d-flex``` and using something else. You're obviously using single-line flexbox - see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set d-block, to get them split into two lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Bootstrap` library then you can play like below snippet.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container my-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <h4>Password is activated</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <button type="button" @onclick="@ToHomePage" class="btn btn-success login-button" role="button">Home</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The correct code is**

```
<div class="login-form-container w-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="alert" role="alert"> 
        <h4>Password is activated</h4>
    </div>
    <button type="button" @onclick="@ToHomePage" class="login-button" role="button">Home</button>
</div>
```

The code you have used, I think you are using Bootstrap library, so as per the bootstrap document "d-flex" should be used with parent element and "flex-column" should be added to break them in two lines.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/ -- Further details can be checked on Bootstrap website

Answer (score -1):

You can use table td tag

```
<div class="login-form-container">
<table>
<td>
            <div class="w-auto d-flex justify-content-center alert" role="alert"> 
                <h4>Password is activated</h4>
            </div></td>
            <td> <div class="w-100 justify-content-center d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button type="button" @onclick="@ToHomePage" class="login-button" role="button">Home</button>
            </div>
        </td>
</table>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: Never ever use tables for layout, unless you are stuck in the last century.

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot. I am using bootstrap. And this makes sense.